# Prolog combinatoric of two lists ignoring the last items

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get the combinatorics of two lists ignoring the last element of both.

the code:

```
isady(_, [_]) :-
    write('stop here'),
    nl,
    false.

isady(E, [H|T]) :-
    write(E),
    write('-'),
    write(H),
    nl,
    isady(E, T).

ady([_], _) :-
    write('stop here'),
    nl,
    false.

ady([H|T], L2) :-
    isady(H, L2);
    ady(T, L2).
```

output:

```
?- ady([a,b,c], [d,e,f]).
a-d
a-e
stop here
a-f
b-d
b-e
stop here
b-f
stop here
c-d
c-e
stop here
c-f
```

expected output:

```
?- ady([a,b,c], [d,e,f]).
a-d
a-e
b-d
b-e
```

As you can see, it doesn't stop when it has to, does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
isady(_, [_]) :-
    write('stop here'),
    nl,
    false.

isady(E, [H|T]) :- 
    T\=[],
    write(E),
    write('-'),
    write(H),
    nl,
    isady(E, T).

ady([_], _) :-
    write('stop here'),
    nl,
    false.

ady([H|T], L2) :- 
    T\=[],
    isady(H, L2);
    ady(T, L2).
```

The new condition  `T \= []` will prevent the use of the last elements of both lists.

**[EDIT]** You can also explicitly use the pattern for a list of length at least 2, to avoid the execution of the "step case" clause with lists of length 1:

```
isady(_, [_]).
isady(E, [X,Y|T]) :-
    writeln(E-X),
    isady(E,[Y|T]).

ady([_], _).
ady([X,Y|T], L) :-
    isady(X, L),
    ady([Y|T], L).
```

Result:

```
?- ady([a,b,c], [d,e,f]).
a-d
a-e
b-d
b-e
true ;
false.
```

Comment: It works, but isn't this a patch instead of a solution?

Comment: @AndréKuljis No, it is not! Observe that pattern ```[H|T]``` matchs all lists of the form ```[_]``` and, when the first clause in the definitions of predicates ```isady``` and ```ady``` fails (due to the call of ```false```), the second clause of the respective definitions is automatically trigged.

Comment: @AndréKuljis I've added another alternative for the correct answer, see [EDIT] .